# Microsoft Exchange Meeting Master Copy

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have a custom application with its own database and a connection to exchange through EWS. Part of this application is a meeting tool which allows users to import exchange meetings and auto invite the other users which also use my application. As part of this tool I need to keep my meetings up to date with exchange, basically maintaining a centralized meeting storage. I can't simply store the user's exchange credentials due to security concerns and I also cannot customize the EWS server in any significant way (ie I cannot add Delegate Access).

The problem is that I am currently simply forcing all users to login to EWS whenever the go to view a meeting's details and it will query EWS to get the details using that user's EWS credentials and access their copy of the meeting. The problem is that there is no guarantee that any user has the same meeting details as any other user. [As is partially explained here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/outlooking/2012/06/11/understanding-meeting-updates/). Is there any way I can force the EWS FindItem call to only use the meeting's public (master) properties? i.e. Whatever version of the meeting the organizer has sent out/updated. I just need all users to return the same details when they query for the same meeting.

One solution I've considered is adding a 'bot' user whenever a meeting is imported into my application, and then just always using that bot's version of the meeting. However, I would really prefer to do something more 'under the hood' that doesn't require this extraneous user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Is there any way I can force the EWS FindItem call to only use the meeting's public (master) properties

No FindItem will only every return you information about what is in the Folder your trying to access. You might want to consider using GetUserAvailiblity to check the organiser https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa494212(v=exchg.80).aspx would be the closest. I would say to make your application work correctly is you need an Service account that has been given at least read access to every users calendar, you can then make a call to get the organiser version of the Appointment which will also contain the user responses. If your using Office365 then the new REST Api does facilitate this in a more secure way eg demon apps https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/

Comment: Thanks, creating a service account using impersonation sounds like its my best way forward. I was hoping I wouldn't need to configure anything special on the exchange server, but this sounds like a reasonable compromise.

These links helped me understand things a bit better: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn722377(v=exchg.150).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb204095(v=exchg.140).aspx